# Square Matrix Algebra - help please!

Tags: matrices, normal-distribution, expectation

I am stuck on a problem in matrix algebra and I would be happy if someone could help me.

Given a square matrix with dimensions "p" given that $\textbf{x}$ $\sim$ N($\mu,\Sigma$) [multivariate normal], how can we show that: E[$\textbf{x}^{T} \textbf{A}\textbf{x}$] = Tr($\textbf{A}\Sigma$) + $\mu^{T} \textbf{A} \mu$ ?

Comment: You shouldn't ask duplicate questions or delete your posts if they havent been answered in a short time.

Answer (score 1):

$x^T A x = tr(x^T A x) = tr(x x^T A)$.

By linearity of expectation, $E[x^T A x] = E[tr(x x^T A)] = tr(E[x x^T A]) = tr(E[x x^T]A) = tr( (\Sigma + \mu \mu^T) A) = tr(\Sigma A) + tr(\mu \mu^T A) = tr(A \Sigma) + tr(\mu^T A \mu) = tr(A \Sigma) + \mu^T A \mu$

by the fact that trace is linear and invariant under cyclic permutations and trace of a scalar is itself.

Comment: Also, original asker -- don't try to deface my answer. It's incredibly rude.